# Naming Convention in c#

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

What is the universally accepted naming convention for c#?
(functions, classes, parameters, local variables, namespaces, etc)

Comment: Universally Accepted? No such thing my friend.

Comment: Fair point - however C#, more than most (because MS guidelines have been fairly visible from the start) has a set of standards that are more often followed than not.

Comment: JohnFx... "generally accepted" would have been a better term to use

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Microsoft has an excellent [set of guidelines on class library design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx), including a [section on naming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx). In short (examples in parentheses):

- Classes/Structs: PascalCase (`WebRequest`)
- Interfaces: PascalCase with I prefix (`IDisposable`)
- Methods: PascalCase (`ToUpper`)
- Properties: PascalCase (`Length`)
- Events: PascalCase (`Click`)
- Namespaces: PascalCase (`System.Collections`; unusual to have two words in one part though)
- Non-constant variables including parameters: camelCased (`keySelector`)
- Constants: PascalCase (`Int32.MaxValue`)
- Enums: PascalCase, singular for non-flags and plural for flags (`HttpStatusCode`, `BindingFlags`)
- Attributes: PascalCase with "Attribute" suffix (`ThreadStaticAttribute`)

Private names are up to you, but I tend to follow the same conventions as for everything else. Hungarian notation (in the style of Win32) is discouraged, although many places use "m_" or "_" as a prefix for instance variables.

Comment: Nice overview @Jon. See this URL for some code examples of the above: http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards

Answer (score 5):

Resharper's guidelines suggest

---

- Types and namespaces **UpperCamelCase**
- Interfaces **IUpperCamelCase**
- Type parameters **TUpperCamelCase**
- Methods properties and events **UpperCamelCase**
- Local variables **lowerCamelCase**
- Local constants **lowerCamelCase**
- Parameters **lowerCamelCase**
- Fields (not private) **UpperCamelCase**
- Instance fields (private) **_lowerCamelCase**
- Static field (private) **_lowerCamelCase**
- Constant fields (not private) **UpperCamelCase**
- Constant fields (private) **UpperCamelCase**
- Static readonly fields (not private) **UpperCamelCase**
- Static readonly fields (private) **UpperCamelCase**
- Enum members **UpperCamelCase**
- All other entities **UpperCamelCase**

Answer (score 4):

The .NET standard from Microsoft is to use [Pascal Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28VS.71%29.aspx) for namespaces, public and protected members (basically anything visible to other classes). For private members and local variables, there's a much wider berth to just do whatever you and your team are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

Don't underestimate the value of following the naming conventions of the platform you are working on as closely as possible.

Look at the reference material for the .NET Framework for examples of how to "fit in" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335.aspx).

Jon Skeet has given you a link to a good writeup by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx

You can also use the standalone Microsoft FxCop (or Code Analysis if you have the Team Edition) http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9aeaa970-f281-4fb0-aba1-d59d7ed09772&DisplayLang=en to check that the naming conventions have been followed. It has built-in rules for the Microsoft conventions, which is another reason you should be using them!

Comment: The FxCop link seems to be dead (it takes me to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/ instead).

Answer (score 1):

Juval Lowy took a stab at this is in [Programming .NET Components](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003471), see this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003338/juval-lowys-c-coding-standards-questions) too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at the slim book called "[Elements of C# Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521671590)" by Baldwin, Gray, & Misfeldt.  The blue book covers naming conventions, and many other aspects of creating consistent, clean, readable code.