# WebResponse does not return any cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I am currently working on a class that helps me creating WebRequest with cookies and POST parameters. But the response.cookies is always empty. How can i grab the returned cookies and send them with the next request?

```
class WebHandler
{
    private string lasturl = "";
    private Dictionary<string, Cookie> cookies;
    public string lastContent;

    public WebHandler()
    {
        cookies = new Dictionary<string, Cookie>();
    }

    public HttpWebResponse request(string address)
    {
        lasturl = address;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Cookie> pair in this.cookies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Sent cookie: " + pair.Value.Name + " = " + pair.Value.Value);
            request.CookieContainer.Add(pair.Value);
        }
        request.Method = "GET";
        if(lasturl != "")
            request.Referer = lasturl;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        foreach (Cookie newCookie in response.Cookies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" new cookie: " + newCookie.Name + " = " + newCookie.Value);
            this.cookies[newCookie.Name] = newCookie;
        }
        lastContent = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return response;
    }

    public HttpWebResponse request(string address, Dictionary<string, string> postParameters)
    {
        lasturl = address;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Cookie> pair in this.cookies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Sent cookie: " + pair.Value.Name + " = " + pair.Value.Value);
            request.CookieContainer.Add(pair.Value);
        }
        request.Method = "POST";

        string postData = "";
        foreach (string key in postParameters.Keys)
            postData += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key) + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postParameters[key]) + "&";


        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        foreach (Cookie newCookie in response.Cookies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" new cookie: " + newCookie.Name + " = " + newCookie.Value);
            this.cookies[newCookie.Name] = newCookie;
        }
        lastContent = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: if there is a redirect then yes , you wont get any cookies , try to parse the response headers and u will see cookies ,

Answer (score 4):

Since `this.cookies` is initially null, your code never enters the loop

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Cookie> pair in this.cookies)
{
     Console.WriteLine(" Sent cookie: " + pair.Value.Name + " = " + pair.Value.Value);
     request.CookieContainer.Add(pair.Value);
}
```

Bad part of it that you never see `request.CookieContainer` is null (Otherwise you would get *null reference exception*) which would show you something is wrong.

Since `request.CookieContainer` is null, HttpWebResponse never gets the returned cookies.

**Solution:** Easy, Just add

```
if (request.CookieContainer == null) 
         request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

after

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
```

---

*PS: You may want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618316/naming-convention-in-c-sharp) about Naming Conventions in c#.*

*PS2: in a method `request` using a variable name `request` doesn't improve readability.*

Comment: But now i can receive cookies and add the to the next request, but my php script does not see any cookies (but in browser everything works fine). I have to do something with domain maybe?

Comment: Very odd behavior...the response object has a non-null cookie container but no cookies.  This definitely worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, so I added `request.AllowAutoRedirect=false;`, now I can get cookies:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
...
request.Method = "POST";
request.AllowAutoRedirect=false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `HttpWebResponse` object's `Cookies` collection is empty, then that means the response had no new cookies. To get access to all cookies for request and response, then read the cookies from the `HttpWebRequest` object instead, like this:

```
foreach (Cookie newCookie in request.Cookies)
{
    // Do something with cookies here for next request
}
```

Comment: I thought i will get all cookies in the response and have to put the same cookies into the next request? Your example foreaches all cookies in the request (that means NO cookies, becuase nobody sets them). I want to keep the cookies from my old response and add it to the next request!

Comment: Well if you have no cookies in the request and no cookies in the response, then you will have no cookies ever.