# Why are methods capitalized differently when they're in a new class?

Tags: c#

Please bare with my I'm very new to programming.

I'm working through a tutorial of C# at the moment. And so far all variables and helper methods that I've created are **capitalizedLikeThis**. I've been doing this all in the **Progam** class.

Today I've created my first new class and within it a method, and the way the method was written **WasLikeThis** with the first letter also capitalized, there was no explanation to this. Is it just a common convention? And if so, is there a specific reason for it?

Thanks,

Comment: refer pascal and camel case in c# programming

Comment: In C# world `WasLikeThis` (camel case) is usually the convention, in java it's more like `wasLikeThis`

Comment: You could find [this article on C# Coding Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) an interesting reading

Comment: @AD.Net thats not hungarian notation

Comment: Some programmers prefer *non-public* members to be spelled without a capitalized first letter.  Like me.  It is a personal preference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Naming Convention in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618316/naming-convention-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @NimChimpsky, you're right, brain fart on my part.

Comment: Methods AreLikeThis, and Properties AreLikeThis... However fields areLikeThis, and property backing fields _AreLikeThis.  At least that's how we do it where I work.  There is no real reason, it's just a standard.  I prefer to do it this way so I know a variable is a property backing field just by it's name.  I know a field is a non property backed field just by it's name, and I know whether I'm dealing with a property or a method just by it's name, because a method IsLikethis() and a Property IsLikeThis.

Comment: Personally i don't think this question is opinion based. The compiler, and even tools like resharper etc. are just enforcing some design rules that are common in the .NET framework. That is a fact.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a reason for it. It is a `Pascal Case naming convention` for method names that is a standard in the .NET framework.

All the types in the framework class library (FCL) follow the mentioned naming convention, and when you create some custom types or add methods to existing types you are augmenting the capabilites of the framework for your specific application needs.

Your method `capitalizedLikeThis` is part of the `Program` class, which has an API that follows the .NET naming conventions. For example  it contains a `ToString()` instance method so you could do:

```
var program = new Program();
Console.WriteLine(program.ToString());
```

So the real question is do you want to add a method to the Program class that breaks the naming convention of the existing API? Consistency is a good thing and that is why **you should follow the convention**.

If you want more information on this topic you can check out the only relevant book for .NET design guidelines containing naming conventions, and many other details related to the .NET framework design decisions:

[http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321246756](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756)

Or read the reduced MSDN article based on the book:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx

Comment: No. If you read the article it says "These guidelines are excerpted from the book Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries, 2nd Edition, by Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Abrams."

Comment: Ah, okay. I have seen that page a dozen times and I never noticed that line.

Comment: I have a hardcopy of the book, so i know it's much larger than the article ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like SyleCop may be beneficial for you.  It will enforce naming standards among other things and you can tweak the options as necessary to meet your naming standards.  The built-in Visual Studio Code Analysis also has rules you can enable for this as well.

Comment: I think this question is about the 'why', not the 'how'.