# Modifications in json format

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This is my api in json format

> [{"tu_id":1,"tu_name":"Akhil","tu_usrname":"Akhl","tu_pwd":"1234","tu_cntno":"423433"}]

I want ID instead of `tu_id` and Name instead of `tu_name`

this is my code in controller

```
public IEnumerable<TestUser> Get()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        TestUserBL userbl = new TestUserBL();
        dt = userbl.TestUserSel();
        var user = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new TestUser
        {


              tu_id = x.Field<int>("tu_id"),
              tu_name = x.Field<string>("tu_name"),
              tu_usrname=x.Field<string>("tu_usrname"),
              tu_pwd=x.Field<string>("tu_pwd"),
              tu_cntno=x.Field<string>("tu_cntno")
            // like wise initialize properties here
        });

        return user;
    }
```

Here I cant change `tu_id`?

Comment: please follow coding conventions in your code as it matters a lot in case of clean code https://stackoverflow.com/a/1618325/5621827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [serialization attributes](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) applied to properties of your `TestUser` class:

```
 [JsonProperty("ID")]
 public int tu_id { get; set; }

 [JsonProperty("Name")]
 public string tu_name { get; set; }
```

Comment: header file to use this attribute

Comment: As he is a beginner I would still suggest renaming class properties as that will follow the code convention as well.Clean coding is what i am suggesting here

Comment: @jitender mixing original `tu_XXX` and 'pretty' property names is not clean coding. Renaming *all* properties - that is clean coding.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Why he will mix them(he should rename all off them)

Comment: @jitender check your answer please

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Updated my answer also any beginner can know that all prop name should follow the same convention and if he goes with your approach what if he need this in future what we will do will he write [JsonProperty("")] on all props?

Answer (score 1):

Change property names(tu_id  to ID and tu_name  to Name etc) in TestUser class they don't follow the conventions [conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1618325/5621827) then do mapping as follow:-

```
 var user = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new TestUser
        {

              Id= x.Field<int>("tu_id"),
              Name = x.Field<string>("tu_name")
        });
```

Comment: Why copy-pasting my anser?

Comment: @jitender that's a definitely copy-paste :) you didn't even mention newtonsoft or attributes

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy ok bro if you think so(Am still not saying this) I edited my answer